# Optimising datastructure/word alignment padding in golang

Tags: go, struct, padding, memory-alignment

Similar to what I've learned in C++, I believe it's the padding that causes a difference in the size of instances of both structs.

```
type Foo struct {
    w byte //1 byte
    x byte //1 byte
    y uint64 //8 bytes
}
type Bar struct {
    x byte //1 byte
    y uint64 //8 bytes
    w byte// 1 byte
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOARCH)
    newFoo := new(Foo)
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(*newFoo))
    newBar := new(Bar)
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(*newBar))
}
```

Output:

```
amd64
16
24
```

- Is there a rule of thumb to follow when defining struct members? (like ascending/descending order of size of types)
- Is there a compile time optimisation which we can pass, that can automatically take care of this?
- Or shouldn't I be worried about this at all?

Comment: I made an example that may provide some insights https://play.golang.org/p/dNWspo2Dxv

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Currently there's no compile-time optimisation; the values are padded to 8 bytes on x64.

You can manually arrange structs to optimally utilise space; typically by going from larger types to smaller; 8 consecutive byte fields for example, will only use 8 bytes, but a single byte would be padded to an 8 byte alignment, consider this: https://play.golang.org/p/0qsgpuAHHp

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type Compact struct {
    a, b                   uint64
    c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j byte
}

// Larger memory footprint than "Compact" - but less fields!
type Inefficient struct {
    a uint64
    b byte
    c uint64
    d byte
}

func main() {
    newCompact := new(Compact)
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(*newCompact))
    newInefficient := new(Inefficient)
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(*newInefficient))
}
```

If you take this into consideration; you can optimise the memory footprint of your structs.

Comment: I'd also like to add that you can visualize your struct by using tools like [structlayout](https://github.com/dominikh/go-structlayout) and [aligncheck](https://github.com/opennota/check) to help you optimize your layout of structs.

Answer (score 17):

> Or shouldn't I be worried about this at all?

Yes you should.
This is also called [**mechanical sympathy**](https://dzone.com/articles/mechanical-sympathy) (see this [Go Time podcast episode](https://changelog.com/gotime/6)), so it also depends on the hardware architecture you are compiling for.

See as illustration:

- "[The day byte alignment came back to bite me](https://web.archive.org/web/20150203040722/http://kernel-panic.runkite.com/2015/01/28/reflect-unsafe-and-other-unsavoury-go-hacks/)" (January 2014)
- "[On the memory alignment of Go slice values](http://blog.chewxy.com/2016/07/25/on-the-memory-alignment-of-go-slice-values/)" (July 2016)

> The values in Go slices are 16-byte aligned. They are not 32 byte aligned.
> Go pointers are byte-aligned.

Comment: I tried to fix the 2014 link as well, but site kernel-panic.runkite.com seems to be gone.

Comment: @ArnaudP Thank you for your edit. I have restored the kernel-panic.runkite.com link as well.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on type of application that you are developing and on usage of those structures. If application needs to meet some memory/performance criteria you definitely should care about memory alignment and paddings, but not only - there is nice article https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/als00/2000papers/papers/full_papers/sears/sears_html/index.html that highlights theme of optimal CPU caches usage and correlation between struct layouts and performance. It highlights cache line alignment, false sharing, etc.

Also there is a nice golang tool https://github.com/1pkg/gopium that helps to automate those optimizations, check it out!

Answer (score 2):

Some guideline

> To minimize the number of padding bytes, we must lay out the fields from
> the highest allocation to lowest allocation.

One exception is an empty structure

As we know the size of `empty` is zero

```golang
type empty struct {
    a struct{}
}
```

Following the common rule above, we may arrange the fields of structure as below

```golang
type E struct {
    a int64
    b int64
    c struct{}
}
```

However, the size of `E` is 24,

When arrange the fields of structure as

```golang
type D struct {
    b struct{}
    a int64
    c int64
}
```

The size of `D` is 16, refer to https://go.dev/play/p/ID_hN1zwIwJ

---

IMO, it is better to use tools that help us to automate structure alignment optimizations

- aligncheck — https://gitlab.com/opennota/check
- maligned — <del>https://github.com/mdempsky/maligned</del>, the original maligned is deprecated. Use https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/fieldalignment
- golang clint

  - you just need to enable ‘maligned’ in the ‘golangci-lint’ settings.
    Example, from the configuration file`.golangci.example.yml`

```
linters-settings:
  maligned:
      # print struct with more effective memory layout or not, false by default
      suggest-new: true
```

Comment: `golang clint` is perfect for my use cases, thank you for suggesting this.

Comment: https://github.com/mdempsky/maligned is deprecated. Suggest to use https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/fieldalignment  instead.

Comment: And last, but not least. Here how you can use **fieldalignment** to resort all the structures in the project. https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/discussions/2298#discussioncomment-1631196