# Re-Order struct to save memory?

Tags: go, struct

I was reading about struct ordering to save memory. I got below `TatProduct` struct which I am trying to reorder so that I can save some memory but I am not able to figure out on how to order it so that I can save memory?

```
type CustomerData struct {
    Name map[Customer]map[int]string
}

type Customer string

type TatProduct struct {
    Ptr            string
    ProductId      int64
    Catalogs       []int32
    Categories     []int
    BaseProductId  *int64
    Code int
    IsCurrent       bool
    CommonValue
}

type YeatStringValue struct {
    Value    string
    ClientId int64
}

type CommonValue struct {
    Stuff   []YeatStringValue
    Carts   []YeatStringValue
    CustomerData
}
```

Is there any utility that can help me analyze my struct?

Comment: I don't know if there are any utilities to do this (that is off topic for SO), but you have no fields that can be collapsed together while preserving alignment. There is only one field value which isn't a multiple of 8 bytes on a 64bit system

Comment: related / maybe dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063530/optimising-datastructure-word-alignment-padding-in-golang

Comment: so struct that I have is fine and doesn't need any alignment? @JimB